# Angular 2 Router how to hide browser url parameter Id's and give alias names

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How do I route to `employeeDetail/23` but represent to the user an alias URL like `/EmployeeDetails`?

---

**Background**

I'm trying to implement Angular 2 routing and when I went to the detail section I see:

```
http://localhost:3444/employeedetail/23.
```

Here I want to hide that `23` on the browser URL.

---

**Example**

http://plnkr.co/edit/QgehylornOgXhTaZX8Yn?p=preview

```
{path: 'crisis-center/:id/:id2', component: CrisisDetailComponent}
```

I want to hide those IDs on the browser URL and instead present an alias route name.

Comment: So you want the url to be http://localhost:3444/employeedetail and you want to show the details for id 23? You would probably need to store the id in local storage so it will persist on a refresh. Also, would you ever want to deep link to this page? If so you'll have to link to something like http://localhost:3444/employeedetail/23, save to local storage, and then redirect to http://localhost:3444/employeedetail. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Does that really make sense. Does this URL work when opened from a bookmark. What if two employees have the dame name?

Comment: Guys, when I click on employee list I go to employee details, why do i want to show his Id on the browser URL, I want to hide it but pass the ID to next page using routeParms. In UI-Router we used to pass stateParams, but it used to have URL = "something" and this only shows up on the browser URL not the actual ID. Why use local storage dont we have anything like alias name that can be shown on browser URL. Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: exactly agree with @GünterZöchbauer this does't make any sense to save this into localstorage , but this state is dependent to too many states , more chances to fail this method

Comment: @VijenderReddyChintalapudi can u post ur answer

Answer (score 1):

use "skipLocationChange" from where you are calling this route
(assuming 23  is your empId):

```
this.router.navigateByUrl("/employeedetail/"+empId,  { skipLocationChange: true });
```