# Angular 4 Route parameters like POST

Tags: angular, routes

Hope you are doing well . I'm trying to develop an app with Angular 4 and i don't know how to pass parameters in my route like POST parameters in http . Can anyone help me ?

For example : Person will show id in the route but i want to hide it !

Thanks A lot !

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153623/angular-2-router-how-to-hide-browser-url-parameter-ids-and-give-alias-names

Comment: Anjum Nawab shaikh it is the same problem but this problem doesn't have a solution yet :(

Answer (score 1):

Say you have an App component Person component. The latter is opened by the router. To achieve what you want, don't configure the person route with params.  Create an injectable PersonService that will be injected into both App and Person component.

The App component will assign the person's ID to a variable in the PersonService using a setter. Inside the setter use EventEmitter to emit the person's ID. Inside the Person component, subscribe to the EventEmitter located inside the PersonService to get the person's ID.

Comment: Yello Yakov Fain thanks for your answer this is what i wanted to do but this is what I was going to do even if I told myself that this is not the best way to do it but thanks for the answer